# Recommendations for missing value imputation - DNA methylation data

Tags: methylation, sequence-analysis, imputation

I'm looking for some options for imputation for a high-dimensional dataset of DNA methylation (bisulfite sequencing) data.  Dimensions on the order of 50-100 samples x ~500,000 CpG loci/features.

I've used K-nearest neighbors, but It seems that this method is not very accurate. As far as I can tell, it limits the minimum number of "genes/features" to impute at one time to something like 1500. which is kind of a lot.

I've also used missForest to impute smaller datasets with greater accuracy, but it seems computationally infeasible to do it on the full 50x500,000 dataset.

I need to impute values because I'm using the data for some statistical modeling which require complete cases.

Anyone know of better alternatives than K-nearest neighbor for large scale imputation?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is still an active field of research.  I have heard of [Phenix](https://mathgen.stats.ox.ac.uk/genetics_software/phenix/phenix.html), which might be appropriate.

Comment: I agree it is still an active area of research. I will check out Phenix, looks like it could be promising. Thanks.

Comment: @Reilstein: can you say anything about your experience with Phenix?

Comment: I never ended up using Phenix because it appears to be tailored for samples/individuals with a degree of relatedness. My particular study doesn't have samples from related individuals. I opted for K-nearest neighbor imputation while keeping the total missing values allowed below 5% prior to imputation.

Comment: The description says "arbitrary level of relatedness".  From my discussions with the author, I would guess that the level of appropriate relatedness  includes the level of relatedness of "unrelated" human individuals.

Comment: ah okay, well I didn't look into it in enough depth apparently.  Thanks for following through with the author.  If I decide KNN Imputation isn't accurate enough for my purposes I will revisit this. Thanks.